# Can Kibana visualizations display custom text highlighting?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I am using Kibana for text analytics. In my Elasticsearch database I have text along with spans annotated by character offsets. For example I might have a document like the following, where the mention of "dog" is tagged as type `ANIMAL`.

```
{
    "text": "The dog barked.",
    "span": [{"start": 4, "end": 7, "type": "ANIMAL"}]
}
```

In my Kibana visualizations I want to pretty print this document so that "dog" is highlighted in a different color.

Note that this is different from [search request highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html). I'm not trying to highlight matching search terms in text. I'm trying to highlight terms specified in the document itself.

How much custom work does it take to make this happen?

Comment: Which visualisation are you using?

Comment: None of them. I can't find a visualization that does this. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.